# Property created but not listed for page

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I’ve added a pair of properties to MediaWiki called:

Has AR Date

Has AR ID

Both of the special pages for these properties specify a data type (Date for the former, text for the latter). I saw the usual message about the jobs queue for both which disappeared after the queue was cleared.

I set a value for both on a page of my wiki, but when I view properties for the page nothing is listed and I see a "This page has no properties" message. I’ve tried rebuilding data, deleting and running storeSetup, running the general update script for MediaWiki and nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What namespace is your page in? Is SMW enabled for it?

Comment: It's in the main namespace. After posting this I tried disabling the ExtraSpecialProperties and SpecialProperties extensions and that seemed to fix it for some reason, although I started getting some errors about being unable to create a DB item. I did setupStore --delete and setupStore, etc, and am waiting for a data rebuild to complete at the moment.